# Compare Two Ordered Dictionaries

Tags: c#, dictionary, ordereddictionary

### Background

I have two ordered dictionaries (old values and new values) created when i update values in a grid. I would then like to compare what values differ and make changes to my data source which happens to be a list.

### Code

This is the method i have created to compare the two dictionaries which are both of type `Dictionary<string,T>`

```
private Dictionary<string, string> FindChangedValues(OrderedDictionary newValues, OrderedDictionary oldValues)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _dictKPVtoUpdate = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> newItem in newValues)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> oldItem in oldValues)
        {
            if (newItem.Key == oldItem.Key)
            {
                if (!newItem.Value.ToString().Equals(oldItem.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    _dictKPVtoUpdate.Add(oldItem.Key, newItem.Value);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return _dictKPVtoUpdate;
}
```

### Problem

I can't seem to cast the dictionaries's values to string, getting the following exception.

> Specified cast is not valid.

on this line

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> newItem in newValues)
```

### Question

Is there a better way to get the changes between the two ordered dictionaries?

How can I cast each value to string in order to compare or is there a way to just compare as they are, without casting?

### EDIT:

### Answer

I was using `KeyValuePair` instead of  `DictionaryEntry` as pointed out.

changed code to the below and the problem was resolved.

**Changed Code**

```
private Dictionary<string, string> FindChangedValues(OrderedDictionary newValues, OrderedDictionary oldValues)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _dictKPVtoUpdate = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (DictionaryEntry newItem in newValues)
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry oldItem in oldValues)
        {

            if (newItem.Key.ToString() == oldItem.Key.ToString())
            {
                if (!newItem.Value.ToString().Equals(oldItem.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    _dictKPVtoUpdate.Add(oldItem.Key.ToString(), newItem.Value.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return _dictKPVtoUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DictionaryEntry` is used in `OrderedDictionary` rather than `KeyValuePair`. Cast to `DictionaryEntry` and use its `Key`/`Value` properties.

> Each element is a key/value pair stored in a [DictionaryEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry(v=vs.110).aspx) object.
>   A key cannot be null, but a value can be.

[OrderedDictionary/Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7)

Comment: Its also worth noting that `DictionaryEntry`'s key and value are of type `object` so will need to convert to strings to put in the `Dictionary<string,string>` that is used for output (or a different return type could be used).

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a dictionary is inefficient.
i would take advantage over the Dictionaries hashes and implement it like so:

```
            Dictionary<string, string> _dictKPVtoUpdate = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        OrderedDictionary newValues =new OrderedDictionary();
        OrderedDictionary oldValues = new OrderedDictionary();

        foreach (DictionaryEntry tmpEntry in newValues)
        {
            if (oldValues.Contains(tmpEntry.Key))
            {
                _dictKPVtoUpdate.Add(tmpEntry.Key.ToString(),tmpEntry.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```